# What does 'static' mean in this ES6 example?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This example is from the docs for Stimulusjs. I've been able to find documentation on ES6 static methods, but this does not look like a method. Or is this some kind of shorthand? Why is there a 'static' key word for a variable?

```
export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = [ "name" ]

  greet() {
    const element = this.nameTarget
    const name = element.value
    console.log(`Hello, ${name}!`)
  }
}
```

Comment: It's a [class field](http://2ality.com/2017/07/class-fields.html), and not valid ES6 but just an experimental syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That syntax is allowed when using [babel's transform-class-properties plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties/). The equivalent in plain javascript would be:

```
class MyClass extends Controller {
  greet() {
    const element = this.nameTarget
    const name = element.value
    console.log(`Hello, ${name}!`)
  }
}

MyClass.targets = ["name"];

export default MyClass
```

EDIT: pre ES6, this would be done as:

```
var MyClass = function () {
  Controller.call(this);
};
MyClass.prototype = Object.create(Controller.prototype);
MyClass.prototype.greet = function () {
    var element = this.nameTarget
    var name = element.value
    console.log('Hello, ' + name + '!');
}
MyClass.targets = ["name"];
```

Comment: No, not on the prototype. Pre es6 it will be a property on the constructor . I'll edit my answer to include what it would look like before classes